# Internet Explorer Converted witdth 100% into 1e2%

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have created a template and it's working perfect in FF and Chrome and in other browser but in Internet Explorer it's making some problem like i have applied with 100% and it's converting it into 1e2%. Please click on below link for better understanding.

[width issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfUM1.jpg)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Show your CSS to help you

Comment: Thanks @Justinas, Ajay's solution is works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please convert minified js/css to normal one.

```
https://github.com/tdewolff/minify
```

during deployment.